# Binding slider ValueChanged event with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a slider on a page, and I am trying to implement a step so that the slider only allows integer values.

In order to achieve that, I am trying to associate an event handler to the **ValueChanged** event. Here is my XAML code:

```
<Slider ValueChanged="OnSliderValueChanged" Maximum="5" Minimum="1" Value="{Binding MaxProductsToOffer}"/>
```

And my event handler:

```
public void OnSliderValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I get the following compilation error:

> Position 15:21. EventHandler "OnSliderValueChanged" not found in type
>   "MyApp.Views.SettingsPage"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slider in Xamarin Forms has explicit `ValueChangedEventArgs` so your event handler should look like this

```
public void OnSliderValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.slider.valuechanged?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

Add the method:

```
void OnSliderValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
}
```

Add it in code behind. 
You do not need your event handled.

Answer (score 0):

> Position 15:21. EventHandler "OnSliderValueChanged" not found in type
>   "MyApp.Views.SettingsPage"

Means that you don't have an `EvenHandler` with the name "OnSliderValueChanged" on `MyApp.Views.SettingsPage`. Where it should be since you pointing to it in XAML -> `ValueChanged="OnSliderValueChanged"`.
So either define it in your page or remove it from XAML.

Regarding your problem, since you are using bindings `Value="{Binding MaxProductsToOffer}"` I assume that you are following the MVVM pattern in your project and that you have a dedicated `ViewModel` bound to `MyApp.Views.SettingsPage`. If so you all you have to do is to bind `Slider.Value` to an integer property in your `ViewModel` that will automatically handle the conversion for you. Here is a solution that does not require any code behind:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SliderTest"
    x:Class="SliderTest.MyPage"
    Padding="50">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
        <Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="5" Minimum="1" Value="{Binding SliderValue}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=slider}, Path=Value}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int sliderValue;
    public int SliderValue
    {
        get => sliderValue;
        set
        {
            sliderValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could: extend `Slider` and use a private EventHandler to manipulate the value or use an EventHandler in your page. Code example can be found [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/ExtendedSlider.cs). However I find it as an overkill compare to my original proposal.

P.S.: If you are using MVVM prefer solutions that does not involve writing code in the UI layer unless it is really necessary.